# If somebody commits some major sins and after a long time he/she is deeply ashamed of that and feels uncomfortable, what should he/she do?

Tags: sin

What is the proper way to get back to a normal life after committing some major sins?

If somebody commits some major sins and after a long time he/she is deeply ashamed of that and feels uncomfortable, what should he/she do?

What to do? How to pray to Allah?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When one repents over his misdeeds it is necessary that he should make the utmost effort to keep himself away from that sin.

- If the sin is about non-performance of duties like `Salāt (daily
  prayers)`, `Siyyam (Ramzan fasting)`, `Zakat (poor tax)` and `Hajj
  pilgrimage`, then, after expressing repentance he should perform Qa‍za
  (repeat to make good) of those duties.
- **If the sin was regarding rights of people**, like usurping someone’s property or money, then he should return it immediately to
  the owner, and if the owner is not alive then to his heirs.

**Tawba of Nasūh** (sincere turning) does not only removes the darkness of sins but it also replaces the darkness with light. The Almighty says :

> "Except him who repents and believes and does a good deed; so these are
>   they of whom Allah changes the evil deeds to good ones; and Allah is
>   Forgiving, Merciful. And whoever repents and does good, he surely
>   turns to Allah a (goodly) turning". (Surah Furqān 25:70-71)

No matter what the committed sin is, it will be pardoned through Tawba Inchaallah ; Allah Almighty says:

> Say: O My servants! Who have acted extravagantly against their own
>   souls, do not despair of the mercy of Allah; surely Allah forgives the
>   faults altogether; surely He is the Forgiving, the Merciful. And
>   return to your Lord time after time and submit to Him before there
>   comes to you the punishment, then you shall not be helped. (Surah
>   az-Zumar 39: 53-54)

Repentance has three conditions:

1- Feeling sorrow for the sin, as the Prophet (SAWS) says, “Repentance is feeling sorrow.”

2- Stopping the sin.

3- Taking a firm decision not to return to the sin again.

there is the story of the Prophet Muhammad(SAWS) with a man who visited him and asked:

> If I performed a sin – O Prophet of Allah – would it be recorded? The
>   Prophet answered: Yes.
>
> The man said: what if I repented?
>
> The Prophet said: It will be erased.
>
> The man added: What if I returned to the sin once again?
>
> The Prophet answered: It will be recorded once again.
>
> The man said: What if I repented?
>
> The Prophet said: It will be erased.
>
> The man said: What if I returned again?
>
> The Prophet said: It will be recorded.
>
> The man asked: What if I repented?
>
> The Prophet said: It will be erased.
>
> The man said: What if I returned again?
>
> The Prophet said: It will be recorded.
>
> The man asked: What if I repented?
>
> The Prophet said: It will be erased.
>
> The man asked: Until when will it be erased?
>
> The Prophet (SAWS) answered, “Allah does not stop bestowing His
>   forgiveness until you get bored of asking for it.”

Answer (score 2):

Listen to your heart and pray as you wish. When praying, don't recite some memorized prayers of somebody. Instead, be sincere and talk to your Rab as you would talk to your friend, knowing that He is able to provide you anything He wills.